# How to make Partial Dependence plots into a scatterplot instead of a line graph from xgboost data

Tags: r, partial

```
library(pdp)
library(xgboost)
param.list <- list(max_depth = 5, eta = 0.01, objective = "binary:logistic", 
           eval_metric = "auc")

house.xgb <- xgb.train(params = params, 
              data = xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(house[ ,1:3]), label = 
house$SalePrice, missing = NA), 
              nrounds = 500)
partial(house.xgb, pred.var = "MSSubClass", plot = T, train = house[ ,1:3])
```

[image: Graph I have]

[image: Graph I Want]Graph I want

https://slundberg.github.io/shap/notebooks/NHANES+I+Survival+Model.html the graph i want comes from this link which uses python. I don't care about the colors or y axis, I just want the scatterplot part rather than the line graph.

I've been using the partial from the pdp R package but if anyone can point me in the direction of another package that would be great. The pdp package only gives a few data points.

Comment: Please always state libraries you've used in code, thanks.

Comment: ok i added the libraries

Answer (score 0):

In the call to `partial()` just set `plot = FALSE` (which is the default). For example,

```
pd <- partial(house.xgb, pred.var = "MSSubClass", 
              train = house[ ,1:3])
head(pd)  # print the data frame
plot(pd)  # basic plot or use ggplot2, lattice, plotly, etc.
```

will return a data frame for which you can make a scatterplot with!

Comment: so that only gives me like 10 data points actually. i ended up figuring this out a few weeks ago. I had to download the package and ran a few of the functions and then edited the function manually.